# PHP - Getting rid of curly apostrophes

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm trying to get rid of curly apostrophes (ones pasted from some sort of rich text doc, I imagine) and I seem to be hitting a road block.  The code below isn't working for me.

```
$word = "Today’s";
$search = array('&#8222;', '&#8220;', '&#146;');
$replace = array('"', '"', "'");
$word = str_replace($search, $replace, htmlentities($word, ENT_QUOTES));

What I end up with is $word containing 'Today&#146;s'.
```

When I remove the ampersands from my $search array, the replace takes place but this, obviously, will not get the job done since the ampersand is left in the string.  Why is str_replace failing when it comes across the ampersands?

Comment: Those curly apostrophes are called smart quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
$word = htmlentities(str_replace($search, $replace, $word), ENT_QUOTES);
```

?

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly easy.  I think I've been coding for too long!

Answer (score 6):

In order for me to get things working properly, I needed something a little more robust than the example @cletus laid out. Here is what worked for me:

```
// String full of rich characters
$string = $_POST['annoying_characters'];

// Replace "rich" entities with standard text ones
$search = array(
    '&#8220;', // 1. Left Double Quotation Mark “
    '&#8221;', // 2. Right Double Quotation Mark ”
    '&#8216;', // 3. Left Single Quotation Mark ‘
    '&#8217;', // 4. Right Single Quotation Mark ’
    '&#039;',  // 5. Normal Single Quotation Mark '
    '&amp;',   // 6. Ampersand &
    '&quot;',  // 7. Normal Double Qoute
    '&lt;',    // 8. Less Than <
    '&gt;'     // 9. Greater Than >
);

$replace = array(
    '"', // 1
    '"', // 2
    "'", // 3
    "'", // 4
    "'", // 5
    "'", // 6
    '"', // 7
    "<", // 8
    ">"  // 9
);

// Fix the String
$fixed_string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
$fixed_string = str_replace($search, $replace, $fixed_string);
```