# strange chars from form to database â€œlikeâ€ a

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting these chars as I insert into a database: â€œlikeâ€. Its suppose to be "like" but it comes out that way.

It inserts into the database that way from a form I submit. I tried htmlspecialchars and addslashes but this did not work.

I am sure this is a simple fix. Just cant find it.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I noticed that the funny chars come from the quotes that Microsoft Word makes.  I used this code and it worked... for now.

```
$Comments = $_POST[Comments];
$Comments = str_replace("”", "\"", $Comments);
$Comments = str_replace("“", "\"", $Comments);
```

Comment: What's the database encoding?

Comment: I don't know how to tell. I had wordpress set it up. I had this issue before.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to support [Unicode](http://docforge.com/wiki/Unicode) characters throughout your app:

1. Set your page encoding to UTF-8.
2. Set your database connection to UTF-8 ("SET NAMES").
3. Set your database storage encoding and collation to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Change your database encoding to UTF-8. This link could be helpful http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/wordpress-and-mysql-character-encoding

Comment: I did your change in the database but it didn't work for the word quotes. See my post above. I updated it. That works for those but I don't know what other chars I might have issues with.

Comment: Ok, glad you solve it. BTW, I've found a similar thread in SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/12252899/263989